# pdf of sum of convex combination of two random variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, density-function

[This paper](https://scholarworks.utep.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2110&context=cs_techrep) claims:

> If we have two random variables ξ1 and ξ2, then we can form their
> mixture if we take ξ1 with some probability w and ξ2 with the remaining
> probability 1 − w. The probability density function (pdf) ρ(x) of the
> mixture is a convex combination of the pdfs of the original variables:
> ρ(x) = w · ρ1(x) + (1 − w) · ρ2(x). A natural question is: can we use
> other functions f (ρ1, ρ2) to combine the pdfs, i.e., to produce a new pdf
> ρ(x) = f (ρ1(x), ρ2(x))? In this paper, we prove that the only combination
> operations that always lead to a pdf are the operations
> f (ρ1, ρ2) = w · ρ1 + (1 − w) · ρ2

However, from any standard text book on statistics,

> The distribution of the sum of the values of two or more underlying random variables is given by the convolution operator.

Is the claim made in the [paper](https://scholarworks.utep.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2110&context=cs_techrep) correct?

Comment: What is this "claim made in the paper" to which you refer?  There is no contradiction between the two quotations: a sum is not a mixture.  They refer to different things.

Comment: Can we not view what the paper is claiming to be mixture of two RV as weighted sum of the RVs?